# What is the etiquette to follow when writing a farewell message for a co-worker leaving permanently on disability?

Tags: professionalism, disability, farewell, retirement

We have a team member who has been with some of us for over 20 years, and the others have been in the industry with him for over 10 years. He had an accident at home that involved a significant head injury, and is no longer able to work.

Given his situation, is there any etiquette I should follow when writing a message for him in a farewell card?

Comment: The same way you'd say goodbye to anybody else you appreciate, I'd imagine.

Comment: I had this idea that I would write a long remenicising letter or thank him for contributions. ...  I think the answer below (short and sweet) is best

Comment: I mean... if you think he'd appreciate a long letter and it's the kind of thing you normally do, go for it. Or short and sweet. Whatever makes sense. Only you know his personality, your office dynamics, your relationship with him, etc.

Comment: @Baronz Oh, sure, if you want to, you can do that. My point was don't let his disability be a factor in what you write.

Comment: The question has attracted some close votes due to being too open ended, so I have made another edit to focus on the etiquette to follow when a coworker retires due to disability (which is a good on-topic question IMHO).

Comment: out of curiosity, does this mean he will be not be able to get any income since he can't work anymore? Or he will have some form of government/assurance income? (i don't know what is your country)

Comment: @giò he's in the United States. I would assume there is some assistance there.

Comment: @MaskedMan Well, it wasn't really the pre-"given his situation" part that was open-ended, that was already understood. It's just the fact that everybody's different and there are too many unknowns (personality, office culture etc.). I mean, heck, I've got a colleague now who would appreciate jokes about his injury more than a sincere farewell (note: don't try this at home). I know other people who would be very bummed out if they got a short-and-sweet, or, say, where the farewell card felt obligatory and awkward. Myself, I'd be annoyed by even the smallest fanfare. It really varies.

Comment: On retirement income: we don't get a pension, but I think he has investments in 401k that he has built up.  He was under 5 years from planned retirement.

Comment: @JasonC Right, while that is certainly true, it also holds in case of people retiring without any disability. The differentiating factor here *is* the "retiring due to disability", and the main question is whether *that* should warrant any special considerations when giving him the farewell. OP would have no reason to ask a question here if the co-worker was retiring "normally". I am not entirely happy with my phrasing there, but that is *my* language limitation. Please edit it to something better if you have some time to spare. Thanks.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

"It was a pleasure working with you. Wish you all the best."

No need to make a song and dance about the disability. Write the farewell message exactly as you would in normal circumstances.

Answer (score 4):

It's similar to retirement.  It's not similar to a new job, leaving to have a baby, etc., so let that guide you.  You may be familiar with people retiring and the sort of things people write then.

In most places I've been, saying you've enjoyed working with them, that you'll miss them, and wishing them well for the future (no specifics) would be a typical note -- 2 sentences max.  Of course the relationship may be closer than that and you might want to say more, but it doesn't sound like it in this case.